# How to add a Grid in Scenebuilder with a particular column having more cells then the rest of column?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

i wish to add a grid layout with each row having different cells. As for now i can add or delete only a row or column, i wish to ask if i can add a cell in a particular row or column.

Eg in the below grid image, i wish to ask how i can add a cell in Column 2 . i mean i want to add more cell in column 2 than the rest of column [image]

Comment: Why not add an 8th row but only populate cell (8,2)? In other words, leave cell (8,0) and cell (8,1) empty.

Comment: In a word, no, you cannot do this with a `GridPane`. Every column will have the same number of rows and each row will have the same number of columns. However, as Slaw pointed out, you do not need to **fill** each cell.

Comment: can i partition one cell into two cell as well

Comment: can i group two grid into one grid ,so that it wont overlap on increasing or decreasing grid window

Answer (score 0):

You can make each column a 1-column GridPane. Each column can have as many rows as you like. Put all those columns in another 1-row GridPane:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        GridPane  grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        for (int i= 0; i< 5 ; i++){
            GridPane column = makeColumn(3+i);
            grid.add(column, i, 0);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(grid));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private GridPane makeColumn(int columns) {
        GridPane column = new GridPane();
        column.setPadding(new Insets(2));
        column.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
            column.add(new Label("  "+i +"  "), 0, i);
        }
        return column;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }
}
```

[image]